# Did any big-iron systems implement offloaded database IO tasks?

Tags: io, database, big-iron

I think I might have a false-memory, but I remember reading about some *big iron* system (1970s to the 1980s, I suppose) that set database benchmark records because it delegated bulk OLTP DML and aggregation for OLAP queries to its peripheral IO hardware and storage-controllers.

*Something* about how engineers realised how this big machine, with its single solitary CPU *intended* for performing all application-specific data processing tasks was so high-end that the system used general-purpose microprocessors (even outright whole computers) in its offboard IO subsystems, such as how it had multiple hard-disk controller units with fully-fledged 8088s and hundreds of KBs of memory and only a fraction of that computing power was used for controlling the disk hardware, the rest of it was going unused - and they saw an opportunity...

Regardless of that anecdote's veracity, I can see that offloaded IO like that *could* be made to work, even in a transactionally-safe environment for certain kinds of operations - and how it's [a case of bringing the program closer to the data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40601991/159145) (instead of bringing the data to the program in the CPU) - if you squint it's almost just like MapReduce works, except much more limited in scope.

So DB operations without any data-dependency (i.e. parallizable DML) like a SQL `UPDATE t SET x = x + 1` could be performed rapidly in-place (and concurrently on multiple disks if the DB was using spanned storage) without the need to read pages into the disk controller's buffer then pass them up to main-memory and eventually write-back modified pages (all while holding an expensive lock)

...Similarly many kinds of aggregation in queries is commutative (such as `COUNT`, `SUM` and `AVG`) so could be performed directly by the disk controller, and even if the data spans multiple disks or controllers the hardware could still perform intermediate aggregation and pass those values up to main-memory instead of the full raw pages.

By the 1990s this technique would have less relevance (e.g. because IO controllers were integrated into HDDs, so didn't need general-purpose microprocessors; and faster IO busses meant they didn't large local buffers either), and storage itself was the main bottleneck: the CPU was always waiting for the disk, not the other way around. Not to mention the effort needed to program an RDBMS to identify which kinds of queries/ops could be safely offloaded w.r.t. transactional integrity.

...but it's the mid-2020s now (*...wow*), and we've got SSDs [that can pull 14GiB/s like it's nothing](https://www.kioxia.com/content/dam/kioxia/shared/business/ssd/enterprise-ssd/asset/datasheet/EnterpriseSSD_DataSheet_E.pdf) - so the idea of performing some kinds of processing *directly on the SSD's onboard controller* to avoid PCIe bus contention is appealing - and even before now, when there's an RDBMS using a huge SAN, it also makes sense for offloaded then.

Comment: ICL had the Content Addressable File Store (CAFS) on innovative hardware, later Son of CAFS (SCAFS) on microprocessors. It's not clear from the overviews I have read whether data modification was executed in the controller; I assume not.

Comment: Database machines (which had dedicated chips optimized for running SQL) were developed in the 1980s.  I used one in 1989/1990.  It was connected to a VAX cluster, which ran the UI and applications.  Sadly, I don’t remember the name.  It’s competition, though, was Exadata, which still exists.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really clear what system you may have heared of, but for sure no mainframe. For one, use of conventional microprocessors for processing in mainframes type systems only started in the late 1990s and only at the very low end. More important, the whole point about mainframes was block orientated operation and streamlined I/O operation with offloading of basic control to sub systems.

*Note, mainframes in this context are /370 type data shovlers, that kind doing financial bookings like your credit card balance, insurance or banking, not supercomputers as their structure and purpose is different.*

## How It Works

The most fundamental aspect were those mainframes differs from today's microprocessors is it's block orientation - despite inventing byte addressing. Programs act primary on data blocks (records), no surprise as they were intended to replace everything, but foremost [unit record equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_record_equipment), aka punch card machinery.

One great idea of [Amdahl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Amdahl)'s [/360 design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360) was to cover I/O behind an abstract set of block orientated high level instructions, which allowed to delegate execution to distinct I/O processors. A machine would have at least one CPU and one or more IOC as dedicated units (*1). Each IOC handled one or more channels which could connect to one or more devices. Such a device might be a printer, reader, tape or disk controller. The later again operating one or more drives. A bit like later SCSI controllers (*2).

Interesting here maybe, that the I/O command, and thus the IOC, doesn't know about the device controllers. All commands send out and responses received are always addresses for the device (*3). For the CPU this means it neither sees the IOC no device controllers, just devices. A view of the I/O structure modern OS only create as result of several software layers is directly presented by basic hardware without any layer inbetween.

I/O was not done by some ports, but using those block orientated I/O commands operating in a chain of data structures (call it parameter record) each describing an operation to do, like searching for a block on a disk, reading or writing that block and so on. Important here, those parameter data may be tailored for a specific device, but was still abstract in structure. That is the read command for the next punch card is the very same as for a tape or disk block (*4).

The ability to chain I/O allows extreme reduction of I/O tasks for the CPU. After reading some catalogue, the CPU would build a list of blocks to be read and hand it over to the IOC in a single I/O instruction and continues operation - usually with another process. It will get notified when the job is done, so the process can be activated again.

*This may highlight another point often ignored about mainframe computing vs. personal computing: Mainframes are optimized sustained thruput, not peak performance. That is getting the a maximum of jobs done in a given time, not the shortest run time for a single job (*5)*

One way to think about an IOC in modern terms might be a DMA controller on steroids with it's own CPU, handling all hose interfaces and devices (*6). Such a tiered and standardized structure of CPU, IOC, controllers and devices is not only extreme versatile, but also offers endless ways of optimization.

Naturally a disk controller always read the whole track, at least until the desired block is found and transferred. From there it was a quick step to as well hold that track in controller memory - in case another block of the same track is needed. That optimization was already reached ca. 1970 and common not much later. With the advent of 'cheap' (*7) semiconductor memory during the 1970s disk controllers got more buffer memory, so they could store tracks from several drives and more than just the last one. by the end of the decade caching controllers were available with enough memory to store most of a disk. All invisible to CPU and IOC - except for speed :))

**That's essentially how mainframe I/O works and why it not only survived until today, but thrived to constantly excels in over all thruput.**

---

### Features Lost

In fact, there are as well  lost - or better no longer used - features which might seem lovely to data base guys and have inspired your assumptions.

For example, in the beginning disks were not organized as blocks of equal size, but more like a bunch of tapes. Each track like a tape of it's own, independent of all other, which could contain any number of blocks of any (varying) sizes. As a result block address could be the same as record address and a program searching for a certain record number would not have to turn that first into a block address, read that block and then extract the record, but straight away issue an I/O with the record number as key - as log as the tape (track) was known. Sounds a bit like database access in hardware, doesn't it?

It gets better as classic mainframe disks do not have an address header like floppies or today's HD (*8), but a key block preceding the data block. That block could itself be of variable length and hold any information, not just a number. As a result, early disks could be managed as a key-value data base with the CPU issuing a single machine instruction pointing to a key to retrieve it's value from disk.

Nifty, huh?

The whole thing was called "Count Key Data" or CKD ([more information here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24085/6659)). All IBM disk storage was based on that system.Use of Blocks of even size and numbered consecutive assectors were considered a special case. Although, during the 1970s more an more access schemes moved over to [CHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector). Still, it wasn't until ca. 1980 that IBM added CHS organization for user access.

Why? **Blocks of equal size managed by the OS was faster**.

This might be surprising with the assumption of the question that putting higher functions near data will improve speed, but it'S simply that CPU processing simply did speed up a multiple of what disks did. So it was faster to have streamlined block transfer but doing handling on the CPU side. This meaning to read more data than needed wasn't an issue as the interface speed anyway surpassed the disk speed - same way as CPU speed did with interface speed.

Well, that and the fact that mainframes are about over all thruput, not peak performance (remember?). It doesn't matter much how fast in real time a single process is that wants to touch lots of data in what he sees as a single operation. Those processes are a few und more often than not a result of bad data base design.

---

*1 - That is except for the very lowest end types were the CPU micro-program also doubled as IOC - think of it like a microprocessor doing I/O in some emulation interrupt.

*2 - The whole idea of SCSI was to replicate a mainframe I/O system on a smaller scale and at lower cost.

*3 - That is except for a few special operations like configuring the controller itself.

*4 - Also the reason why a mainframe can boot from every device able to understand a read command. Anything specific to handle that device is handled by its device controller,not the IOC or CPU.

*5 -  We tend to focus on peak thruput nowadays, but it's the tools that work 24/7 that get more done. Same way as Usain Bolt may outrun any marathon athlete on the first 100m or maybe even 500m, but he'll be trailing way after a fit 50 year old on the full distance.

*6 - Intel had planned a somewhat similar structure for the 8086 with the [8089 I/O processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8089). A dedicated 16/20 bit CPU and DMA that could interact with the main CPU quite similar as on mainframes. Maybe not as simplified, but quite close in performance (considering it's still a 1978 micro). The PC would have been a complete different beast if IBM had used the 8089 instead of kludgeing on an 8 bit DMA and a page register. Then again, such design only pays of in multi tasking systems, not a single user single tasking PC. But they should have known from their own history :(

*7 - Cheap in mainframe terms.

*8 - They are like blown up floppy disks, not in anyway like prior mainframe drives - which lead to quite some compatibility issues when mainframes started to use those drives as well around 1990. After all, by then those drives were so cheap (*7),that there was no longer any gain in continuing development of mainframe specific drives.

Comment: I grew up a microcomputer kid, and never understood the "why" of mainframes, until I started reading your answers to various questions.  This is one of the best you've done.